# Oracle 12c installation on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

hi guys i have a problem to oracle 12c installation on ubuntu 15.10.

I following this steps.
- I downloaded oracle database 12c x86_x64 version.
- unzip zips.
- go to database folder on terminal and run runInstaller
- open setup and started installation.
- building Client shared libraries step of installation i take this eror
 "error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib' of makefile oracle installation"

thanks for helping.

note: i controlled the x86 or x64 version not problem here

Comment: Wait... Since when is Oracle supported on **Ubuntu**? I suggest you to use **Oracle Linux** on a **VirtualBox** if it is for **learning purpose**, as it is free.

Comment: here's link how install Oracle 11.2 xe to ubuntu
http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html

it's about 11.2 xe but maybe will be same for 12c

Comment: hi. they extended to Linux in the workplace so i using ubuntu and i tried this tut but it didn't work. :(

Comment: Did you try this one? It worked for me with ubuntu 15.04.
http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/02/14/how-to-install-oracle-12c-database-on-ubuntu-15-04-vivid-64bit-easy-guide/

Comment: hi, i didn't try it. I am trying now. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can work for you:

from: http://ccm.net/faq/4405-linux-installing-oracle-11g-on-ubuntu#installing-packages-needed-for-pre-installation

in simple term, you have to install alien and then create groups & users for oracle-db (see the guide), and *then* you can install oracle with alien, it's don't seem to be a pretty way, maybe vagrant in the future can help us.

there is this other guide with more details and steps: http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/04/17/how-to-install-oracle-11g-r2-database-on-ubuntu-15-04-vivid-64bit-gnulinux-easy-guide/

Good luck ;)

UPDATE:

I finally install oracle 11g-XE on linux mint 17.3 following this guide:

https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/installing-oracle-11gxe-on-mint-and-ubuntu/

I don't put all the steps because there are soo many, if you can, use centOS linux to install oracleDB because the rpm installer are tested (or developed) for that versions of linux, another way it's a bit tricky (like in debian based OS like bugbuntu or linux mint), good luck